# How to auto delete row from child table if row from parent table gets deleted

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-design, eloquent

I have two tables (customer and bookings)

customer_table:

```
|       id       |
|      name      |
|   created_at   |
|   updated_at   |
```

bookings_table:

```
|       id         |
|     product      |
|   customer_id    |
|    created_at    |
|    updated_at    |
```

how do I create a migration file that will delete all of bookings related to customer when a customer is deleted?

Comment: Set foreign key onDelete cascade

Comment: You can set foreign key to child table

Comment: are you using Models if than share customer and booking model details

Comment: Another choice is using `trigger`

Answer (score 2):

Simply set foreign key onDelete to be cascaded

```
Schema::create('bookings_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('product');
    $table->unsignedInteger('customer_id');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('customer_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('customer_table')
        ->onDelete('cascade')
        ->onUpdate('cascade');
});
```